# How to align inner html with other dynamic objects - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, innerhtml

I have dynamic checkbox and textbox where it also display values through inner html. However, the values are not aligned with their proper textbox and checkbox which makes it confusing when choosing.

Is there a way to put a divider or border or align after every object to properly separate the values?

[Here is the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Tdx.png)

```js
function populate(model, destination) {
    var mod = document.getElementById(model);
    var des = document.getElementById(destination);
    var cri = document.getElementById("criteria");
    var qty = document.getElementById("qty");

    var optionArray = [];
    if (mod.value == "Model-A") {
        des.innerHTML = "";
        if (cri) cri.innerHTML = "";
        if (qty) qty.innerHTML = "";
        optionArray = ["Dog", "Cat"];
    } else if (mod.value == "Model-B") {
        des.innerHTML = "";
        if (cri) cri.innerHTML = "";
        if (qty) qty.innerHTML = "";
        optionArray = ["Fish", "Bird"];
    }

    for (var option in optionArray) {
        if (optionArray.hasOwnProperty(option)) {
            var pair = optionArray[option];
            var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.name = pair;
            checkbox.value = pair;
            des.appendChild(checkbox);

            var label = document.createElement("label");
            label.htmlFor = pair;
            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pair));

            des.appendChild(label);
            des.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
    }

    updateCriteria();
}

function updateCriteria() {
    var text = "";
    var cri = document.getElementById("criteria").value;
    var models = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
    var model = "";
    var criteria = document.getElementById("criteria");
    var qty = document.getElementById("qty");

    for (var i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        var qtytextbox = document.createElement("input");
        var wrapper = document.createElement("span");
        model = models[i].innerText;

        if (model == "Dog") {
            wrapper.className = model;
            qtytextbox.className = model;
            wrapper.innerText =
                "They can read our emotions—if we’re happy, sad or angry.\n";
            criteria.appendChild(wrapper);
            criteria.appendChild(br);
            qty.appendChild(qtytextbox);
            qty.appendChild(br);
        } else if (model == "Cat") {
            wrapper.className = model;
            qtytextbox.className = model;
            wrapper.innerText =
                "They are inquisitive, friendly, playful, active, loving and independent.\n";
            criteria.appendChild(wrapper);
            criteria.appendChild(br);
            qty.appendChild(qtytextbox);
            qty.appendChild(br);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td> Choose one: </td><td>
      <select id="model" name="model" onchange="populate(this.id, 'destination')" >
        <option value="select">--Select Animal--</option>
        <option value="Model-A">Pets</option>
       <option value = "Model-B"> Model-B </option>
      </select> 
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
 <tr>
  <th><center> Animal: </th></center>
  <th><center> Characteristic: </th></center>
  <th><center> Others: </th></center>
 </tr> 
 <tr>
  <td><center><div id="destination" style = "width:230px; word-wrap: break-word"></center></div></td>
  <td><center><div id="criteria" style = "width:350px; word-wrap: break-word"></center></div></td>
  <td><center><div id = "qty" required></td></center>
 
 </tr>
```

Comment: You're currently using only one table cell per column. You should probably separate each column into multiple cells.

Comment: I agree with @eicksl . You need to have separate rows for each animal.  Then everything should align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments section, you need to append a new `<tr>` for each entity of selected model. To achieve that you could create an empty "template" row, clone it for each entity and fill its `.destination`, `.criteria` and `.qty` with appropriate data. I would do it like this:

```js
const data = {
  "Model-A": {
    options: [
      { name: "Dog", characteristics: "They can read our emotions—if we’re happy, sad or angry.\n" },
      { name: "Cat", characteristics: "They are inquisitive, friendly, playful, active, loving and independent.\n" }
    ]
  },
  "Model-B": {
    options: [
      { name: "Fish", characteristics: "Fish characteristics" },
      { name: "Bird", characteristics: "Bird characteristics" }
    ]
  },
}

function createRow(option, tableRowClassName) {
  const row = document.getElementById('template').cloneNode(true);
  const dest = row.querySelector('.destination');
  const cri = row.querySelector('.criteria');
  const qty = row.querySelector('.qty');
  
  createDestination(dest, option);
  createCharacteristics(cri, option);
  createQty(qty, option);
 
  row.id = `template_${option.name}`;
  row.classList.add(tableRowClassName);
  
  return row;
}

function createDestination(container, option) {
  const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  const label = document.createElement("label");
  const id = `checkbox_${option.name}`;
  
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.name = option.name;
  checkbox.value = option.name;
  checkbox.id = id;
  label.htmlFor = id;
  label.innerHTML = option.name;
  
  container.appendChild(checkbox);
  container.appendChild(label);
}

function createCharacteristics(container, option) { 
  const wrapper = document.createElement("span");
  wrapper.innerHTML = option.characteristics;
  container.appendChild(wrapper);
}

function createQty(container, option) {  
  const qtytextbox = document.createElement("input");
  qtytextbox.placeholder = option.name;
  qtytextbox.name = `qty_${option.name}`
  container.appendChild(qtytextbox);
}

function populate(value) {
  const model = data[value];
  const tableFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  const table = document.getElementById('result-table');
  const tableRowClassName = 'added-row';
  
  // reset table
  Array
    .from(table.querySelectorAll('.' + tableRowClassName))
    .forEach(row => row.remove());
  
  model.options.forEach((option) => {
    const row = createRow(option, tableRowClassName);
    tableFragment.appendChild(row);
  });
  
  table.appendChild(tableFragment);
}
```

```css
#template {
  display: none;
}

#result-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#result-table td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> Choose one: </td>
    <td>
      <select id="model" name="model" onchange="populate(this.value)" >
        <option value="select">--Select Animal--</option>
        <option value="Model-A">Pets</option>
        <option value = "Model-B"> Model-B </option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="result-table">
  <tr>
    <th><center> Animal: </center></th>
    <th><center> Characteristic: </center></th>
    <th><center> Others: </center></th>
  </tr> 
  
  <tr id="template">
    <td>
      <center>
        <div 
          class="destination" 
          style = "width:230px; word-wrap: break-word">
        </div>
      </center>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <center>
        <div 
          class="criteria" 
          style = "width:350px; word-wrap: break-word">
        </div>
      </center>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <center>
        <div class="qty"></div>
      </center>
    </td>
    
  </tr>
</table>
```